# Should we merge the [import] tag into the [data-import] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

What's the difference between the [[import]](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/import) and [[data-import]](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-import) tags?

As far as I can tell, these tags are functionally identical.

I've taken a mix of questions from each tag and jumbled them into a list.

Can you guess which question has which tag?

- [How can I sucessfully import 3D surface and features from ArcGIS 10 into Sketchup 8?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13515/how-can-i-sucessfully-import-3d-surface-and-features-from-arcgis-10-into-sketchu)
- [How to import/export geographic information (gml or csv file) to geodatabase?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10144/how-to-import-export-geographic-information-gml-or-csv-file-to-geodatabase)
- [How to batch import GDAL supported raster files into GRASS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41269/how-to-batch-import-gdal-supported-raster-files-into-grass)
- [What tools are available for uploading gis data to a database?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/931/what-tools-are-available-for-uploading-gis-data-to-a-database)
- [How to best prepare CSV files for use in ArcGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45050/how-to-best-prepare-csv-files-for-use-in-arcgis)
- [How to convert KML to shapefile without losing attributes?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33826/how-to-convert-kml-to-shapefile-without-losing-attributes)

I couldn't.

Can we merge the [import] tag into the [data-import] tag?

I feel that favoring the [data-import] tag is more descriptive.

---

**UPDATE:** It's been done, community opinion was clear and the tags have been merged (*so no need to vote anymore :)*

Comment: +1 for merging but I would make import the master.

Comment: Thanks for taking a poll, Matt. When does voting end? Who makes the final call?

Comment: The poll is already conclusive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

vote up this answer if you prefer [import](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/import) as master

Comment: Ok, that's a pretty clear consensus. It is done. :)

Answer (score -2):

vote up this answer if you prefer [data-import](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-import) as master

Comment: it was suggested this answer be deleted as the deed has been done. I'm leaving it though so the record of the poll is retained (and closing the Q instead).