# Meta could use "close because it's no longer relevant" flag

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, meta

Meta could use a **close** flag of type *"no longer relevant"*.

Examples where this would be appropriate:

- [Should we merge the [import] tag into the [data-import] tag?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3306/should-we-merge-the-import-tag-into-the-data-import-tag)
- [Community Promotion Ads - 2012](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/540/community-promotion-ads-2012)
- [What should be our domain name?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/what-should-be-our-domain-name)
- [2013 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3111/2013-moderator-election-qa-question-collection)

The current practice of using `duplicate` for this purpose is a kludge (and in the case of the merge tags example, there is no dupe to point to).

Answer (score 4):

Having just been through a number of Close Votes where the subject was definitely on-topic I also agree with the no longer relevant suggestion.  The questions were not off-topic according to the purpose of this site, they were merely old or an answer had been discovered by the Original Poster (OP).  So, pedantically, I didn't feel I could vote to close the question as none of the reasons for closure seemed to apply.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the intent of this new custom Close reason being made available for Meta questions but I do not think that it needs to be  implemented because we can already propose closure using the Other category saying:

> This question is about something
>   which is no longer relevant because [give reason].

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that if a question in GIS Meta is on-topic, unanswered and it is believed to be "not relevant anymore", then there should be an **answer** explaining why.

That would be likable to avoid discussions about why a post was marked "not relevant anymore" in cases the reason is not so clear (and people could vote in the answer agreeing with it, or not). And the question would remain open for competing/complementary answers.